# use old offline phone as a hardware wallet?

Tags: transactions, wallet, offline-transactions

here's what i want to do:

store my private key on an offline phone.
use that offline phone to generate a signed transaction and generate a QR code for me to scan/broadcast with my online phone.

does this exist?!? i cannot find an app to do it

seems like the most secure/convenient way to use bitcoins.

Comment: Beware: phones are built for connectivity. To make a truly offline device you'll want to take extra steps to ensure you remove **all** connective functions (wifi, bluetooth, etc) from the device. Otherwise this is a reasonable idea, though I'm not sure what software is mobile-ready to display signed transactions in the way you need.

Comment: that's a good tip. i thought even if i have 100 virus on my phone it won't matter because it'll never go online. but what if the virus re-enables online o.o

also i need to make sure to encrypt phone's data, just in case it's stolen there's no keys on the drive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

electrum android app can do this! check it out, it's perfect!
also seems like a nice wallet with a lot of features.

your watch-only online electrum can create an unsigned transaction with QR code.
your offline electron can scan then sign it & generate a QR code for you to broadcast with online electrum!

Comment: i recommend using multisig instead. same idea, just an extra level of security by also requiring the key from your online phone